# Detect when the serves is about to sleep on CloudBees

Tags: java, jersey, cloudbees

I wrote a REST server application using Jersey, and I deployed on CloudBees. Since I have a free account the server will go to sleep after 2 hours of inactivity. Before this happens I would like to save data on a database; how could I detect the sleep event on the cloudbees server? Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting application to hibernate is a standard servlet container shutdown, so a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextDestroyed%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) can handle this. Another option is for you to have a periodic Timer task to store data on DB, as application may also just crash for various reason, and you'd them have data lost

Comment: I would recommend periodic - as the app could move any time, best to not rely on events like that.